# How to use a different STL with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

I want to use a different STL with g++ instead of its default libstdc++. What is the easiest way to do this?

I found -nostdinc++ flag which inhibits g++ from looking for its STL headers but this is only a compile time thing. It will still make g++ link against its own STL.

So I need to find a way to inhibit the linking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One easy method is to build  with gcc rather than g++ - this won't link in the default C++ libraries, but will still compile .cpp files as C++ code. You will have to specify your alternative libraries explicitly on the command line.

Comment: I see. Do I have to explicitly specify any other libraries  (other than the STL) that g++ would otherwise have included but will be skipped now that I am using gcc? Thanks.

Comment: There are also -nostdlib and -nodefaultlibs options.  But they seems less usefull for the OP purpose and he would need to provide more support functions or explicitly link against libc.  Note also that the g++ driver automatically provides -lm while gcc doesn't.

Comment: gcc should still link in the necessary C libraries etc. though not the maths library as AProgrammer observes.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the [STLport](http://www.stlport.org/) instead of the default gcc stl implementation. In my Ubuntu when I install the package there is a library for static linking (/usr/lib/libstlport.a). This is just a guessing I don't know if it will actually work.