# Does link line order for supc++ really matter?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

This is a follow up to an earlier question -

[How to use a different STL with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227615/how-to-use-a-different-stl-with-g)

I can now get my code to build while using a different STL. However, I still need to link -lsupc++ (along with said different STL)

I see anecodal references that -lsupc++ should be the last library on the link line. I cannot find a definitive answer to this. Currently, it is not the last library on the link line for me and things seem to work fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Link line ordering is a picky, cranky thing. The rule is that libraries have to be linked in reverse dependency order: if object A is in libfoo, and depends on object C from libbar, then the link line needs to go `-lfoo -lbar` and not the other way around. Having `-lsupc++` at the end makes sure that if any other libraries you're linking depend on objects in libsupc++, the dependency will resolve correctly. In your case, the trailing libraries probably just don't have any unresolved dependencies.

Comment: Good advice. But some versions of ld are so primitive that you will actually have to name the library twice on the command line to resolve circular dependencies.

Comment: Wow. I've never run into one of those, and God willing I never will, but this is good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I now understand a little bit more about this whole linking game :) 

btw, I assume that this ordering matters only when you have a static library in the menagerie (i.e. supc++) ? i.e. if there were only dynamic libraries, then the ordering should not matter?

Comment: My understanding is that it matters regardless.